# Convert an IntegerBinding to a DoubleBinding

Tags: javafx

This may seem like a simple question, but it turns out it's not all that easy (or i can't find any info on how to do this).

I simply want to convert an IntegerBinding i have, namely `Bindings.size(families);` to a DoubleBinding so that if i do something like this `Bindings.divide(Bindings.size(families),Bindings.size(familiesAll))` i don't get the result of an integerdivision. Maybe there are otherways to achieve what i want, but converting Bindings is something so essential it must be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of options:

```
Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> 
    1.0 * families.size() / familiesAll.size, 
    Bindings.size(families), Bindings.size(familiesAll));
```

or:

```
Bindings.divide(Bindings.size(families).add(0.0), Bindings.size(familiesAll));
```

or:

```
Bindings.size(families).add(0.0).divide(Bindings.size(familiesAll));
```

or:

```
DoubleProperty familiesSize = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
familiesSize.bind(Bindings.size(families));
Bindings.divide(familiesSize, Bindings.size(familiesAll));
```

Comment: Thanks for the options! I thought of the .add(0.0) too, but that seems so... workaround-y?^^

Comment: Yes; it is a bit. The problem is that `IntegerBinding.getValue()` returns an `Integer`, so you kind of get stuck with integer arithmetic. I added another, perhaps less hacky, option.

Comment: The last one was actually what i was looking for. So simple i couldn't figure it out. Thanks!